# How can I configure Tomcat 9 without apt-get installation?

Tags: server, ip, tomcat

I have installed my Tomcat 9 from this [source](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi). Just downloaded the **tar.gz** file and extracted it.

Then I went into the ../conf/server.xml file to change the port from 8080 to 80.

[image]

And then I started the Tomcat server.
[image]

**Question:**

Before chaing the port from 8080 to 80, I could connect http://192.168.x.x:8080 inside my browser. But with port 80, ip http://192.168.x.x:80, I can't.

How can I configure Tomcat 9 so it will open for my other computer to access? I must have missed something?

Comment: Do you have `ufw` enabled?  Try typing `ufw status` and it should give you information on the firewall or respond with "Status: inactive".

Comment: @tudor Deactivated.

Comment: Please install the `nmap` package and run `nmap -p 80 localhost` and include the output in your question.

Comment: What happens if you use wget http://localhost from the same machine? Also check if tomcat has actually started and see if its complaining about something in catalina.out file

Comment: @tudor I got "PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http
"

Comment: Is Tomcat actually running?  `ps -Af | grep java` and check logfiles for errors.

Comment: @tudor Yes. -Dcatalina.home=/home/hp/Program/Tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/hp/Program/Tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Comment: @tudor It works with 192.168.x.x:8080, but not with 192.168.x.x:80

Comment: And with another port, like 9090?

Comment: @tudor Yes. 192.168.x.x:9090 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ports below 1024 can be opened only by root.**

You can do one of three things:

**Option 1 - Run tomcat as root**

```
$ sudo sh startup.sh
```

**Option 2 - Redirect port 80 to another port using iptables**

With this option, you keep Tomcat running on a port above 1024 and use `iptables` to *forward* that port to Tomcat.  (e.g. 80 -> 8080)

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

**Option 3 - Upgrade privileges to java applications**

**Either:**

Change CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE, e.g.

```
`$ sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /path/to/java`
```

**Warning** that will enable all java applications to open ports lower than 1024.

**or use authbind**

```
$ sudo apt install authbind
$ sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ sudo chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

Comment: I tried the touch, authbind and chmod method. Didin't work.

Comment: But are you saying that running as root did?

Comment: Yes!. Always root.

Comment: Wait! Now it's working!

Comment: Now it stopped to work.

Comment: And now it's running. It seems that it very important to use first 1. sudo sh startup.sh, then 2. sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080, then 3. sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80 and then 4. sudo chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/80 . If you want to close the server, then use sudo sh shutdown.sh and not sh shutdown.sh

Comment: Do I need to run those commands everytime I start up Linux?

Comment: By the way! I cannot acces the http://192.168.x.x from my phone, only at this computer.

Comment: No.  Each of those options **do different things**.  Only use one of them, not all of them!  Running as root (direct to port 80) is different to forwarding to a different port (80 -> 8080) which *is different again* to elevating privileges.